# how to invoke a iphone native application from webview

Tags: iphone, native, webview

i have a application which has 2 parts one is a webview and other is a native iphone application.
I want to invoke a native iphone application from a website inside 
 a webview.

Answer (score 1):

If by webview you mean a webpage that you open in Mobile Safari you can link to your native iPhone app by registering a custom URL scheme for your app.

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html has a fairly clear description on how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean opening something like Mail or SMS from within your app, then you can use a URL like sms:// or mailto: